# How do I dynamically create event listeners with square bracket notation in node?

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to use a loop for dynamicaly generating event listeners
in node. But I'm unable to properly target the button objects.
I've used -global- and -this- but both return an error.

```
var Gpio = require('onoff').Gpio,
button1 = new Gpio(17, 'in', 'both'),
button2 = new Gpio(27, 'in', 'both'),
button3 = new Gpio(22, 'in', 'both'),
button4 = new Gpio(23, 'in', 'both');

var i = 5;

while(i-->1)
{
console.log(i);
global["button"+i].watch(function(err, value) {
if (err) exit();
x++;
console.log("button "+i+" has been pressed" );
})}
```

How can I correctly point to the objects inside the while loop?

Thanks

Comment: Try another approach: `var buttons=[new Gpio(...),new Gpio(...),...];buttons.forEach(function(button){button.watch(...`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What is your reason behind your approach?
Is my approach not possible?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's actually "not possible", but I think it's not easy to implement, and not quite "JavaScript-y".